# Issue with external keyboard emulation with usb RFID Reader

Tags: flutter

I have a RFID Reader which emulates keyboard input. I want get card number with it in my flutter application and then submit to api. I have tried onChanged Event but it fires before the reader could sent all the card numbers. If I try it with onSubmitted, this never fires because the Reader emulates Carriage Return after typing all card digits. Please help

I have tried onChanged which fires as soon as first digit is printed by reader which is wrong as I need all digits and also onSubmitted never fires because it doesn't work with external keyboard Enter Key. Also I have tried RawKeyboardListener, but then all key strokes are sent to RawKeyboardListener and there is no input to send in TextBox.

I expect once all card digits are read be reader and sent to TextBox, then it should be submitted to api automatically and not on button click as Submit Button.

```
class _TagCardState extends State<TagCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final cardController = new TextEditingController();
  final focusNode = new FocusNode();
  final keyboardNode = new FocusNode();
  StudentData currentStudent = StudentData(name: "Ready to Tag");
  final TextStyle h1 = TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0);
  final TextStyle h2 = TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0);

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterFirstLayout(context));
    keyboardNode.addListener((){
      if(keyboardNode.hasFocus){
        print("keyboard focused");
      }
    });
    focusNode.addListener((){
      if(keyboardNode.hasFocus){
        print("texbox focused");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    cardController.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
    keyboardNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(keyboardNode);
  }

  void _handleKeyEvent(RawKeyEvent key) {
    final _kEnter = 66;
    if (key is RawKeyDownEvent && key.data is RawKeyEventDataAndroid) {
      RawKeyDownEvent ev = key;
      RawKeyEventDataAndroid evAndroid = ev.data;
      print(evAndroid.keyCode);
      if(evAndroid.keyCode == _kEnter){
        print("Enter Key");
        print("Text box value :" + cardController.text);
//        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
      }
    }
  }

  void resetStudentData() {
    this.setState((){
      this.currentStudent = StudentData(name: "Ready to Tag");
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(keyboardNode);
    });
  }

  void showLoading() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()),
        content: Container(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            height: 50.0,
            child: Text("Loading...")
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendRequest(cardNumber) async {
    final data = {
      "card_number" : cardNumber
    };
    focusNode.unfocus();
    this.showLoading();
    httpPut("student/card/tag", data).then((response) {
      cardController.clear();
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Map responseData = json.decode(response);
      print(responseData);
      if(responseData['success']){
        this.setState((){
          this.currentStudent = StudentData(
              name: responseData['data']['student_name'],
              cls: responseData['data']['class'],
              rollNumber: responseData['data']['roll_number'],
              image: responseData['data']['image'],
              in_out: responseData['data']['in_out'].toUpperCase()
          );
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(keyboardNode);
          new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3), resetStudentData);
        });
      }
      else {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(keyboardNode);
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(responseData['message']),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            )
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("KMV Attandence"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Center(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RawKeyboardListener(
                        child: TextField(
                            enabled: true,
                            obscureText: false,
                            controller: cardController,
                            onSubmitted: (text) => this.sendRequest(text),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: 'Tag Card'
                            ),
                          ),
                        focusNode: keyboardNode,
                        onKey: (key) => _handleKeyEvent(key),
                      ),
                      Text(this.currentStudent.name, style: this.h1),
                      Text(this.currentStudent.cls, style: this.h2),
                      Text(this.currentStudent.rollNumber, style: this.h2),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green
                        ),
                        child: Text(this.currentStudent.in_out, style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ]
              )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class StudentData {
  final String name;
  final String cls;
  final String rollNumber;
  final String image;
  final String in_out;

  const StudentData({
    this.name = "",
    this.cls = "",
    this.rollNumber = "",
    this.image = "",
    this.in_out = ""
  });
```

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.471], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (6 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Please post your code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I have added code. Thanx

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sir Please help. I have some print statement for debugging. Please excuse me for that.